# ImportError: No module named smtplib,with python2.7

Tags: python-2.7

I use python2.7 coding but an error importing block me, I had check  system variables(win7-64bit), and import smtplib in python2.7 shell is ok.
when I run my module with pycharm or python shell, error is 'ImportError: No module named smtplib', now I have no idea deal with the problem, can you help me?

1. I have tried to system variables
2. 'import smtplib' in python shell is ok. but in module

Platform_SendMail_Attachments.py

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import mimetypes
import os.path
import smtplib

import email.MIMEBase  # import MIMEBase
import email.MIMEImage  # import MIMEImage
import email.MIMEMultipart  # import MIMEMultipart
import email.MIMEText  # import MIMEText


def sendTestreport(file_name, mailto, mailSubject, mailText, From):

    server = smtplib.SMTP("mta1.corp.ebj.elong.com")
    main_msg = email.MIMEMultipart.MIMEMultipart()
    ......
```

error:'ImportError: No module named smtplib'

Comment: Are you executing the script inside a Virtual Environment?

Comment: not in virtual env

Comment: Can you type `where python` in the same command prompt from which `smtplib` is accessible? Also could you check the python interpreter from *project settings* of **pycharm**?

Comment: D:\wb\webapp>where python
D:\Python27\python.exe
use the shell in the path, 'import smptlib' is ok;
and pycharm setting which project interpreter is the same path above, thanks, I have checked again, but not OK